# Whats the difference between Entities, Business Objects, Data Transfer Objects and Business Model Objects?

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, multi-tier

Not able to get a clear distinction between these concepts that are used very often in multi-layered architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me:

1) Entities/Business Objects/Business Model Objects - the actual objects (nouns) in the business domain.  For example "Order" and "OrderItem".  "Order" could have a property of "OrderDate", and function called "GetOrderItems"

2) Data Transfer Objects - serializable property bag representations of your Entities.  Using the example above, the function "GetOrderItems" would be missing from your "Order" DTO.

Comment: Just happened to see your answer :-). Thanks